# Aorus Gaming 5 Mobo Flashes Green Once and Doesn't Turn on

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, computer-building

I'm in the process of upgrading my gaming PC for the first time in 6 years and this MB is giving me a bunch of issues.

So far, I've had to buy another CPU after the 7th gen one I bought was incompitable (my own fault but still frustrating that I wasted all that money)

Now, having checked requirements, my RAM and CPU are both compatible (DDR4 and 9th gen 1151 pin respectively), my GPU is itself only a few weeks old so shouldn't cause any problems, and my CPU and CPU cooler are installed properly.

Here we get to the meat of my question:

Upon plugging in my PCU and turning the PCU on, my motherboard flashes green once; on pressing the power button, the computer doesn't boot. I've actually tried to boot with a bunch of different configurations but with no luck (all the way down to nothing plugged in except the bare essentials needed to boot).

My last suspicions are:

1. I've plugged everything in wrongly and it's short circuiting
2. I've exposed the mobo to static while building and it's short circuiting
3. My PSU (Corsair GS 800 - 800W) isn't powerful enough for the MB.

I've given up on trying to contact Gigabyte about this, they seem to want to make it as hard as possible to contact customer support; and I'd really rather fix this myself than call a tech for my own ego's sake. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your PSU is plenty powerful for your motherboard.

Comment: In that case, have you got any idea what I should be looking for?